# if i received a 1989 stock certificate from GMC in December of 2010 is it worth anything?

Tags: stocks

if I have a GMC stock certificate from 1989 but did not receive it until December of 2010 is it worth anything?

Comment: By “GMC”, are you referring to General Motors?

Answer (score 5):

By "GMC" I assume you mean General Motors Corporation.

General Motors Corp (NYSE:GM) declared bankruptcy in June 2009 and the stock symbol changed to GMGMQ and traded was moved to OTC/Pink Sheet.  In Juy 2009 it changed trading symbol and name to MTLQQ/Motoros Liquidation Company.

At the end of March 2011, it was determined that the secured and unsecured debt exceeded the value of the assets of the company, there was nothing left for shareholders.

The final trade of MTLQQ happened on March 31 2011 for $0.0422.  After this, trading was terminated and remaining shareholders received $0 for their shares.

i.e. It is not worth anything apart from as a collectors item.

Source: Internal databases at Norgate Data